# Cannot pass parameters to super(); in a class's constructor that extends RealmBaseAdapter (Realm)

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a problem that I cannot pass the parameters "context, realmResults, automaticUpdate" to super(); in a class's constructor that extends RealmBaseAdapter. See my code and the screenshot to be clear for you.

*** My code:**

```
package com.twitter.i_droidi.notah;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

public class RealmModelAdapter <T extends RealmObject> extends RealmBaseAdapter<T> {

    public RealmModelAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<T> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate)
    {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*** Screenshot:**

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qpbf.png)

*** Realm version: 1.0.1**

*** Android Studio version: 2.1.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Realm 0.90.0+, you should be using the separate [`realm-android-adapters`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) project (currently `compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'`). In which [RealmBaseAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java) has the following constructor signature:

```
public RealmBaseAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<T> data) {
   ....
}
```

So you would have

```
super(context, realmResults);
```

---

In Realm 2.0.0+, the context parameter is no longer needed.

```
public RealmBaseAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<T> data) {

public RealmRecyclerViewAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<T> data, boolean autoUpdate) { // <-- autoUpdate always recommended to be `true`
```

Answer (score 3):

With Realm latest version, the constructor for RealmBaseAdapter is changed to

`RealmBaseAdapter(android.content.Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<T> data, boolean automaticUpdate)`

So, you need to replace `RealmResults<T>` with `OrderedRealmCollection<T>` in your code.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem still exists after I changed `RealmResults<T>` to `OrderedRealmCollection<T>`.

Comment: I am not able to download the io.realm dependency to try to replicate it at my end. Can you upload a sample mini project to github and give me the repository url?

Comment: I just follow this tutorial: [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/)

Comment: I found the solution of the another problem.. just delete the parameter `boolean automaticUpdate`.